# Добавить возможность удалять users из базы json data на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Есть json файл http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, я добавил в HTML всех юзеров со значениями name, username, email.

Как мне вывести каждого юзера в div и чтобы для каждого юзера была своя кнопка "delete user" через метод ajax "DELETE"? Не получается прикрепить кнопку к каждому юзеру.

Comment: удалить где? из dom или базы  или из файла json?

Comment: на сколько я знаю метод ajax "DELETE" удаляет из json базы и в dom тоже

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: urlCall + '?' + $.param({"Id": Id, "bolDeleteReq" : bolDeleteReq}),
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: callback || $.noop,
    error: errorCallback || $.noop
});